# PHP returns object as null occasionally and unintentionally

Tags: php

We have PHP code in production that sometimes fails with "Call to member function on null", although the same code path executes fine several times before that in one invocation. We have a test that reproduces the error consistently at the same run of the loop.

I already proved that the object gets created correctly in the factory even if it gets returned as null. The factory method must not return null in any case, as indicated in the DocBlock. This question is not related to nullable return types or something like that.

The process does not exceed memory or runtime limitations and I already tried turning off the garbage collector, but no luck. The error happens both in PHP 7.0 and 7.3 on Debian, did not try on other versions or operating systems.

I am not allowed to paste the real code here, but I wrote a simple mockup to explain in more detail. Please keep in mind that this demo code will not result in the error, it is just meant to show the general structure of the program that runs into this fault.

```
// Three placeholder classes with common methods
class Bender
{
    public function common()
    {
        echo "Bend, bend!" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class Clamper
{
    public function common()
    {
        echo "Clamp, clamp!" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

class Worker
{
    public function common()
    {
        echo "Work, work!" . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

// abstract class with static factory to produce objects
abstract class MomCorp
{
    /**
     * Factory to create one of several objects
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Bender|Clamper|Worker
     */
    public static function factory($name)
    {
        $type = self::managementDecision($name);
        switch ($type)
        {
            case "bender":
                $robot = new Bender();
                break;
            case "clamper":
                $robot = new Clamper();
                break;
            default:
                $robot = new Worker();
        }

        // optional QA works flawlessly here, object is fine all the time!
        // $robot->common();

        return $robot;
    }

    public static function managementDecision($name)
    {
        // irrelevant magic happens on $name here
        return "bender";
    }
}

foreach (['Rodriguez', 'Angle-ine', 'Flexo', 'Billie'] as $newName)
{
    echo "$newName: ";
    // The next two lines break after some loops - why?
    // The perfectly functional object in factory gets returned as null
    $bot = MomCorp::factory($newName);
    $bot->common();
}

// SAMPLE OUTPUT
// Rodriguez: Bend, bend!
// Angle-ine: Bend, bend!
// Flexo: Bend, bend!
// Billie: Call to a member function common() on null
```

Has anyone experienced the same and has any hints on what might cause such an error and how to fix it?

Comment: When that happens, the default is not Worker(), but null. That code here is 100% totally ok. Maybe the (origin) switch statement has some fault?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but that is not the case. The object is always properly created inside the factory, I tested for that, right before the object gets returned to the caller. So right before the return everything is fine, but outside code gets a null value returned. The real code does not use the intermediate variable, it directly does "return new Bender();". I just used $robot for debugging, like the commented out $robot->common() call.

Comment: But the error strictly said, you are calling a method on null. So the entity is **not** created. Maye something is bad in the constructor of Bender().

Comment: Sadly this is not the case here. The object gets instanciated flawlessly inside of factory. Only the returned value from factory is null after a few calls. The first runs of factory (which all result in the same class being instanciated) work fine as well.

Comment: Are you using some OPcache, XDdebug or something like that

Comment: 'after a few calls', what happens in these calls, is there any manipulation of the object going on?